# Restrict JQuery each() to scope of ascx control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have some JQuery code which wires up an autocomplete dropdown - one for state and one for sex.  I am trying to use the same control for both cases.  When I run a `each(function ()`   I would like to differentiate between the two controls.

The .ascx code contains the following HTML.

```
<div id="acDropDownDiv" runat="server">
    <input runat="server" id="autoCompleteID" style="visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;" />
    <input runat="server"  id="autoCommpleteValue" style="width:100px;margin-right:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;height:22px;" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    InitAutoCompl(); 
</script>
```

The javascript `InitAutoCompl` wires up like this:

```
var ncicValList = <%=GetNcicValues()%>;
        var ncicList = $.parseJSON(  ncicValList );


      $('*[id*=acDropDownDiv]:visible').each(function () {

                    var inputs = $(this).find("input");

                    var autocompleteHiddenID = inputs[0];
                    var autocompleteDropDownValue = inputs[1];

      $(autocompleteDropDownValue).autocomplete({
           source: ncicList,...

    }
```

I have two of these controls on the same page... 
One is supposed to display US states and the other is supposed to display Gender {M, F, Unknown }.  The values come from the code behind function `GetNcicValues` which passes back some JSON data.  That function returns either the states or the gender depending on an attribute `NCICCategoryID` that is set at the control level like this.

```
 <autoCompl:JQAutoCompl ID="acIdState" NCICCategoryID="48"   runat="server" style="width:100px" />
```

The problem is that the JQuery function,  `$('*[id*=acDropDownDiv]:visible').each(function ()` .  will apply to both the `state`  and the `sex` controls and that both controls end up with State data, because the state is loaded last.

Is there a JQuery function that can somehow say, "Only apply this `each()` to `<input>` elements within the .ascx control where the javascript resides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `.each()` handler, you can check any property you want on the object currently being iterated.  So, if you want to check the id, you can check `this.id` and your code can branch appropriately based on which of the `.each()` objects is the current one.